# How to fix fixed time step?

Tags: c++, time, timer, timestamp, frame-rate

I tried to implement fixed time step from https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

```
void Core::MainLoop() {
    float t = 0.0f;
    float dt = 0.01;

    float currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
    float accumulator = 0.0f;

    while (!quit) {

        float newTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        float frameT = newTime - currentTime;
        currentTime = newTime;

        accumulator += frameT;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
                exit(0);
            }

            MenuInput(event);
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        while (accumulator >= dt) {
            Update(dt);
            t += dt;
            accumulator -= dt;
        }

        Draw();

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
}
```

In this tutorial he set delta value to 0.01 so it never changes. If so, how my position updates in different fps? Also, when I've openged my game menu input slowed down and some inputs like enter didn't even work.

How to make my loop works in fixed time step and allow user to set fps?

Comment: Nobody? :C :c :C